# External file cart empties when using browser back button

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, cart

I have the following code in an external file(same domain) to get the current cart details, and I'm getting all details without any issues.

The problem is,  when I go to the checkout page using 'Go to checkout' and press browser back button this cart gets empty. I mean only on this external file.

When I click the 'view and edit cart' and uses the browser back button the cart is fine.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", true);
ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL);

require '/var/www/html/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$obj = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State')->setAreaCode('frontend');

$storeManager = $obj->create("\\Magento\\Store\\Model\\StoreManagerInterface");
$storeManager->setCurrentStore(1);

$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');

// Getting the object managers dependencies 
$quote = $obj->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session')->getQuote();
$shoppingcart = $obj->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');

$imagehelper = $obj->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');

// Get quote and cart items collection
$quote = $shoppingcart->getQuote();
$quoteitems = $quote->getAllItems();

// Getting cart 
$cart= $shoppingcart->getCart();  

// Getting the subtotal of the cart
$subtotal = number_format($quote->getBaseSubtotal(), 2);
$qty = 0;

$arrProducts = array();
$mediaurl= $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
$baseurl = $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();

$j = 0;
foreach ($quoteitems as $item)
{
    $arrProducts[$j]['productID'] = $item->getProductId();
    $arrProducts[$j]['productName'] = $item->getName();
    $arrProducts[$j]['productQty'] = $item->getQty();
    $arrProducts[$j]['productPrice'] = number_format($item->getPrice(),2);

    $qty += $item->getQty();

    $_product = $obj->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($item->getProductId());
    $arrProducts[$j]['productUrl'] = $_product->getUrlKey();
    $arrProducts[$j]['productImage'] = $mediaurl.'catalog/product'.$_product->getSmallImage();

    $j++;
} ?> 

<div class="CustomMiniCart">
<?php 
    if($qty > 0 && !empty($arrProducts)){ ?>
        <span class="miniCartWrap">
            Cart Subtotal: <b>$<?php echo $subtotal; ?></b>
            <span class="numItems"><b><?php echo count($arrProducts);?></b> Item(s) in Cart</span>
            <a href="https://example.com/checkout/" class="chk">GO TO CHECKOUT</a>
        <?php 
        foreach($arrProducts as $product){ ?>
            <span class="proWrap">
                <span class="left"><a href="https://example.com/<?php echo $product['productUrl'] ?>/"><img src="<?php echo $product['productImage'] ?>" /></a></span>
                <span class="right"><a href="https://example.com/<?php echo $product['productUrl']?>/"><?php echo$product['productName']?></a><br><br>
                    <b>$<?php echo$product['productPrice']?></b><br><br>Qty: <?php echo $product['productQty']?>
                </span>
            </span>
    <?php } ?>
        <span class="viewcart"><a href="https://example.com/checkout/cart/">VIEW AND EDIT CART</a></span>
        </span>
    <?php }else{ ?>
        <span class="emptyCart">You have no items in your shopping cart.</span>
   <?php  } ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case, your cache is Enable, so you can't get values in an external file.

Once **you disable the cache**, it will work fine

Comment: It returns to respective pages, but the cart is getting empty

Comment: I can go to checkout page with cart and I placed an order.

Comment: https://example.com/checkout/cart/  check your site address

Comment: I'm not using example.com, using my site address. when you are on the checkout page try the browser back button, then the cart gets empty. Only on that particular page!

Comment: The problem is, when I go to the checkout page using 'Go to checkout' and press browser back button this cart gets empty. I mean only on this external file.

When I click the 'view and edit cart' and uses the browser back button the cart is fine.  Read my Question please..

Comment: Are you check with the same browser?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92298/discussion-between-arunprabakaran-m-and-asr).

Comment: Kindly check solution